# sed systemcall in python produces SOH character on macOS 10.12.4

Tags: python, bash, sed, system-calls

I am trying to replace certain characters in a .h-file using a python script that does a sed-systemcall.

This is the line in the variables\ orig.h of which I want the '10' replaced with a value in an array:

```
#define PACKET_DELAY_TIME_A 10
```

If I run a sed-command in bash, so e.g.

```
sed -E 's/(#define PACKET_DELAY_TIME_A).*/\1 2/' variables\ orig.h > variables.h
```

this works completely fine and the output is as expected, namely the '10' is replaced with a '2'

However, when I use a python systemcall to do it, e.g.

```
import os

pckt_delay_A = ["1","2","5","10","20"]
command = "sed -E 's/(#define PACKET_DELAY_TIME_A).*/\1 " + pckt_delay_A[1] + "/' variables\ orig.h > variables.h"
os.system(command)
```

this produces the SOH-character instead of the expected '#define PACKET_DELAY_TIME_A'

```
\u0001 2
```

in my output file. Any idea on what causes this and how to get the expected output? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you replace ' " + pckt_delay_A[1] + " ' by ' " + "2" + " ' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a raw string. With a normal string, `\1` is interpreted by Python, which means to put a character with ASCII code `1` into the string, not being passed to the shell.

```
command = r"sed -E 's/(#define PACKET_DELAY_TIME_A).*/\1 " + pckt_delay_A[1] + r"/' variables\ orig.h > variables.h"
```

Alternatively you could write the code that does this in Python, using its `re` module, rather than calling out to `sed`.